# Count words for all posts by all authors

Tags: posts, query-posts, count

So I got this code from another query and it works for one single post.

However, I want to show the `total words of all the published posts by all authors`. How do I modify this or is there a wp function that exists?

functions.php:

```
function prefix_wcount(){
    ob_start();
    the_content();
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    return sizeof(explode(" ", $content));
}
```

Template:

```
<?php echo prefix_wcount(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a function to get all the published posts and count the words.

```
function wpse410818_count_published_words() {

    $posts = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => array( 'post' ),
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    ));
    
    $count = 0; //Starting words count
    if ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
            $posts->the_post();
            //Add to the word count
            $count += str_word_count(trim(strip_tags(strip_shortcodes(get_the_content()))));
        }
    }
    
    echo $count;
}
```

This will query the database everytime it runs, therefor, you might want to cache the result and update it when a new post is published or an existing post is modified.

Comment: Thank you. Let me look up on caching.

Comment: Although I have marked this as correct, the total count is wrong. I just counted manually in all of my 11 posts and it shows `2,342 words` while your code shows `1616` words.

Comment: @ElaineByene There are few reasons this count may differ. This one removes all the HTML Tags as well as the content printed using shortcodes. There's also possibilities that when the HTML tags are removed, two words are being merged (like, while removing a `<br>` tag). You can check for solutions to properly convert the content into a single string, but the counting solution would be the same.